# Why does "Debug Sampler" break down "Authorization" from another sampler?

Tags: jmeter

As you can see on screens, when I try to use just "Debug Sampler" I get "Authorization" issue in other sampler. But when I use "Debug PostProcessor" all looks fine. Who can describe first behavior? Thanks a lot!

[image: Screen_1]

[image: Screen_2]

JMeter 4.0 | Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put Debug Sampler than according to [scoping rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)

> Other elements are hierarchical. An Assertion, for instance, is hierarchical in the test tree. If its parent is a request, then it is applied to that request. If its parent is a Controller, then it affects all requests that are descendants of that Controller. In the following test tree:

Pre Processors are same as Assertion example, 
all Pre Processors are processed before **Sampler** (e.g. Debug).

When you put Debug PostProcessor, it doesn't trigger any other elements and therefore in your case `access_token` and `token_type`, which are pre processors , execute only when you add Debug Sampler and generate an error because it recreate token when you not expected it.

You can move pre processors under Authorization request so it will be executed only before it